# does Qstandarditemmodel removerows removes data from memory?

Tags: pyqt5

I have a Qtableview that uses qstandarditemmodel. This table have sensitive information so I want to make sure that all the data from the table is removed from memory as well.

Here is how I clear the table:

```
self.tableViewModel.removeRows(0, self.tableViewModel.rowCount())
```

Does this remove the data from memory as well?

Comment: Yeah, why do you think you don't?

Comment: That does it (just like `self.tableViewModel.clear()`). But if you're uncertain about that, you should be worried about *a lot* of other things, by the way.